# npm run build / deploy error on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am trying to compile files with webpack and npm for my reactJS applciation.

When I run npm start, it all goes well.
When I run npm run deploy or npm run build it does not work under a windows environment. It does work under a linux environment.

Does someone have an idea why ?

My files :

package.json

```
{
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "webPath": "web/",
  "nodePath": "node_modules/",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.1",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "^3.0.3",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.14.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-css-url-rewrite": "^0.3.5",
    "grunt-cssjoin": "^0.3.0",
    "grunt-postcss": "^0.7.1",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "matchdep": "^1.0.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.0.2",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.0.4",
    "webpack-shell-plugin": "^0.4.2"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.4.3",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.3.19",
    "grunt-postcss": "^0.7.1",
    "history": "^1.17.0",
    "i18next": "^2.5.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.11.1",
    "radium": "^0.16.2",
    "rc-switch": "^1.4.2",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.1.2",
    "react-router": "^1.0.3",
    "react-router-redux": "^3.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.1.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "selfupdate": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^0.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node webpack.dev-server.js",
    "build": "webpack",
    "deploy": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config webpack.production.config.js"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var node_modules_dir = path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules');

var devFlagPlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    __DEV__: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(process.env.DEBUG || 'false'))
});

console.log(__dirname);

var config = {
    entry: [
        'babel-polyfill',
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:3000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './app/Resources/react/app.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'web/js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/'
    },
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'eval',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        devFlagPlugin
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loaders: ["react-hot","babel-loader?plugins=transform-runtime&presets[]=es2015&presets[]=stage-0&presets[]=react"],
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'app/Resources/react')
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
/*
 new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
 'fetch': 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch'
 })
 */
```

webpack.dev-server.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
var config = require('./webpack.config');

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    quiet: false,
    noInfo: false,
    contentBase: "./assets"
}).listen(3000, 'localhost', function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('Listening at localhost:3000');
});
```

webpack.production.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var node_modules_dir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');

var config = {
    entry: [
        'babel-polyfill',
        './app/Resources/react/app.js'
    ],
    debug: false,
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'web/js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loaders: ["babel-loader?plugins=transform-runtime&presets[]=es2015&presets[]=stage-0&presets[]=react"],
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'app/Resources/react')
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: []
};

module.exports = config;
```

I get the following error with npm run build

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586] (c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation.
>   All rights reserved.
>
> D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev>npm run build
>
> > FoodMeUp@1.0.0 build D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev
> >     webpack
>
> D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev Hash: 9cb8c898ada89430aa7c
>   Version: webpack 1.13.1 Time: 3353ms    [0] multi main 64 bytes {0}
>   [built]
>       + 739 hidden modules
>
> ERROR in ./app/Resources/react/components/subscription/total.js Module
>   not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'lodash' in
>   D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev\app\Resources\react\components\subscription
>   @ ./app/Resources/react/components/subscription/total.js 19:8-25

my total.js file :

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { updateSubscription } from '../../actions/subscription';
var _ = require('lodash');

...
```

I get the following error when I launch npm run deploy

D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev>npm run deploy

> > FoodMeUp@1.0.0 deploy D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev
> >     NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config webpack.production.config.js
>
> 'NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586 npm ERR! argv
>   "C:\Development\nodejs\node.exe"
>   "C:\Development\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run"
>   "deploy" npm ERR! node v6.2.2 npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5 npm ERR! code
>   ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! FoodMeUp@1.0.0 deploy: `NODE_ENV=production
>   webpack -p --config webpack.production.config.js` npm ERR! Exit status
>   1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the FoodMeUp@1.0.0 deploy script
>   'NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config
>   webpack.production.config.js'. npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest
>   version of node.js and npm installed. npm ERR! If you do, this is most
>   likely a problem with the FoodMeUp package, npm ERR! not with npm
>   itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm
>   ERR!     NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config
>   webpack.production.config.js npm ERR! You can get information on how
>   to open an issue for this project with: npm ERR!     npm bugs FoodMeUp
>   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via: npm
>   ERR!     npm owner ls FoodMeUp npm ERR! There is likely additional
>   logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev\npm-debug.log

and my npm-debug.log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Development\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Development\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'deploy' ]
2 info using npm@3.9.5
3 info using node@v6.2.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'predeploy', 'deploy', 'postdeploy' ]
5 info lifecycle FoodMeUp@1.0.0~predeploy: FoodMeUp@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle FoodMeUp@1.0.0~predeploy: no script for predeploy, continuing
7 info lifecycle FoodMeUp@1.0.0~deploy: FoodMeUp@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle FoodMeUp@1.0.0~deploy: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle FoodMeUp@1.0.0~deploy: PATH: C:\Development\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev\node_modules\.bin;C:\Development\nodejs;C:\img;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Development\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Development\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.0;C:\Net Generation\FireFox\;C:\Development\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.9\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev\node_modules\typescript\bin;C:\Development\nodejs\;C:\Development\ruby\bin;C:\Development\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.0;C:\Development\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.9\bin;D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev\node_modules\typescript\bin;C:\img;C:\Users\Sébastien\AppData\Roaming\npm
10 verbose lifecycle FoodMeUp@1.0.0~deploy: CWD: D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev
11 silly lifecycle FoodMeUp@1.0.0~deploy: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
11 silly lifecycle   'NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config webpack.production.config.js' ]
12 silly lifecycle FoodMeUp@1.0.0~deploy: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle FoodMeUp@1.0.0~deploy: Failed to exec deploy script
14 verbose stack Error: FoodMeUp@1.0.0 deploy: `NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config webpack.production.config.js`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Development\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:245:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Development\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:852:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
15 verbose pkgid FoodMeUp@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev
17 error Windows_NT 10.0.10586
18 error argv "C:\\Development\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Development\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "deploy"
19 error node v6.2.2
20 error npm  v3.9.5
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error FoodMeUp@1.0.0 deploy: `NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config webpack.production.config.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the FoodMeUp@1.0.0 deploy script 'NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config webpack.production.config.js'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the FoodMeUp package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config webpack.production.config.js
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs FoodMeUp
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls FoodMeUp
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the configuration file is not 100% correct. See details below:

- need to import 'webpack' mobile before using it (webpack.config.js),
  i.e., `const webpack = require('webpack');`
- need to import `path` module before using it (webpack.config.js),
  i.e., `const path = require('path');`
- `devFlagPlugin` is not defined
- also exclude the `node_modules` directory in the loader

  ```
  module: {
      loaders: [
          {
              ....
              exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/')
          }
      ]
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two different problems.

**Lodash is missing?**

Now, I'm not an expert in Webpack so somebody may point out something obvious that I don't see...but...when you say it doesn't work under Windows, have you tried it on multiple Windows systems?

If this issue is only on one system or it's a PITA to get onto a second box or whatever, try:

1. Delete the `node_modules` directory
2. Execute `npm cache clean` to be sure you'll start fresh when you reinstall
3. Re-install with `npm i --verbose > npm-install-log.txt`

If the install *still* doesn't work, you'll have an install log to review to see if something is failing to compile or there's some other wacky error that may not be visible after install.

**NODE_ENV on Windows**

The `NODE_ENV=production <commands>` syntax is a *nix thing but [not a Windows/DOS thing](https://superuser.com/questions/79612/setting-and-getting-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt).

In this case, you may find it easier to create a `.bat` file for this where you set the variable on the first line and call the command on the second.  However, this won't work on *nix platforms so....maybe:

1. Create two scripts and two entries in `package.json`, one for each OS. If it's a simple project that's mostly maintained by hand, that's probably cool.
2. Create a `deploy.js` script, executed by node, that sets the `NODE_ENV` variable, calls webpack via the [node api](http://webpack.github.io/docs/node.js-api.html) to do the work.  This *should* be OS independent and is a single script...

Answer (score 0):

You can set environment variables in a cross-platform manner by using [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env):

```
"deploy": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config webpack.production.config.js"
```